# Mostrar los datos en Editext con OkHttp Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

estoy teniendo dificultades en mostrar los datos que se obtiene mediante 1 array de objecto al realizar la peticion Get mediante OkHttp.

Al ejecutar via web el la respuesta y dato en json es correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi clase vehiculo donde se implementa el método buscar por parámetro.

```
 private val client = OkHttpClient()
fun listarvehiculo_porparametro(url : String,parametro:String) : ArrayList<evehiculo> {
    //var lista = ArrayList<eclientes>()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(url + "?codigo=" + parametro)
        .build()
    client.newCall(request).execute().use {
            response ->
        if (!response.isSuccessful){
            Log.i("Error: ", "--------")
        }
        else {
            val jsonarray = JSONArray(response.body?.string())
            for(i in 0 until jsonarray.length()) {
                val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonarray.getString(i))
                Globales.listarvehiculos.add(
                    evehiculo(
                     jsonObject.get("modelo").toString(),
                        jsonObject.get("placa").toString(),
                        jsonObject.get("nombreconductor").toString(),
                        jsonObject.get("empresa").toString(),
                        jsonObject.get("lugar").toString()

                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
    return Globales.listarvehiculos
}
```

En mi otra clase conductorvehiculo es donde hago el llamado a este metodo para luego tratar de mostrar la busquedad en un Editext, pero hasta el momento no tengo exito en realizar este paso.

```
var listado : ArrayList<evehiculo> = ArrayList()
var sp = svehiculo()
```

override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
when(p0?.id){

```
        R.id.btnbuscarpedido -> {
            listado.clear()
            OBTENERDATOS()
          //  println(listado)


        }

    }
}

private fun OBTENERDATOS(){

    var parametro = findViewById(R.id.txtbuscadorvehiculo) as EditText
    var modelo = findViewById(R.id.txtmodelovehiculo) as EditText
    var placa = findViewById(R.id.txtplaca) as EditText
    var nombreconductor  = findViewById(R.id.txtnombreconductor) as EditText
    var empresa = findViewById(R.id.txtempresa) as EditText
    var lugar = findViewById(R.id.txtlugar) as EditText

    listado  = sp.listarvehiculo_porparametro(Conexiones.busquedadvehiculoparametro,parametro.text.toString())
  
        modelo.setText(listado.get(0).modelo_vehiculo)
        placa.setText(listado.get(1).placas_vehiculo)
        nombreconductor.setText(listado.get(2).nombreconductors_conductor)
        empresa.setText(listado.get(3).empresas_codnuctor)
        lugar.setText(listado.get(4).lugars_conductor)
    
}
```

Talvez me estoy equivocando en como invocar este metodo y mostrarlo en mis textview.
el erro me marca en la siguiente linea:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.autonortrujillosac, PID: 23052
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1605)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
    at okhttp3.Dns$Companion$DnsSystem.lookup(Dns.kt:49)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.kt:164)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.kt:129)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.kt:71)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:205)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:74)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.initExchange$okhttp(RealCall.kt:255)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:32)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at com.example.autonortrujillosac.services.svehiculo.listarvehiculo_porparametro(svehiculo.kt:22)
    at com.example.autonortrujillosac.controller.conductorvehiculos.OBTENERDATOS(conductorvehiculos.kt:84)
    at com.example.autonortrujillosac.controller.conductorvehiculos.onClick(conductorvehiculos.kt:66)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Qué error es el que marca? Es importante agregar esta información.

Comment: @Jorgesys si acabo de actualizar la pregunta indicando el error, por favor tu gentil apoyo, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al obtener el error `NetworkOnMainThreadException` indica que estás realizando una operación en el hilo principal lo cual no es correcto.

Esto no es una solución correcta, ya que estás desactivando una política permitiendo que todas las operaciones se puedan realizar en el hilo principal.

```
val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
```

**La solución es implementar [**Corrutinas**](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines?hl=es-419)** ó simplemente llama el método dentro de un Thread usando `runOnUiThread`:

```
Thread({
    runOnUiThread({


        //Actualiza UI

    })
}).start()
```

Comment: De acuerdo investigare sobre las Corrutinas.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución , me falto agregar la siguiente linea de codigo en el metodo OnCreate

```
    val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
```